# Popping random item in a stack

Tags: c#

I can't seem to figure how to pop an item of a stack using the elemental feature. Can someone please tell me how to do so?

Relevant code:

```
Stack<Cards> stackOfCards = new Stack<Cards>();
```

I have previously put items into this stack.

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 52);

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
    stackOfCards.ElementAt(randomNumber);//how do i pop this?
}
```

P.S. Do stacks start at 0 or 1? So for a deck of cards would it be 0-51 or 1-52?

Comment: I thought a stack by definition is FILO... I thought you only pushed and popped from the top... Have you inspected what ElementAt is returning... I would think that's more of a "Peek Element At".

I think what you want is just an array or list

Comment: Stacks don't access items by index; there is no *need* to define whether they are 1 or zero indexed since you can't do anything to an item at a given position.

Comment: @Rikon `ElementAt` is a LINQ method, not a method of `Stack`.  `Stack` implements `IEnumerable`, so it is iterating the entire sequence up to that element.

Comment: `"Do stacks start at 0 or 1?"` - Neither.  Stacks aren't indexed, they expose only the "current" or "top" item.  Any given implementation of a stack may internally have an indexable data structure, but that index isn't exposed externally to the stack.

Comment: Why are you pulling out random cards from a deck?  Should you not generally only be pulling from the top anyway?

Comment: @Servy Ah, thx... Admittedly, stack isn't something I use real frequently, shy of some simple queuing stuff.

Comment: It is not appropriate to completely edit your question into an entirely different question once you get an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of a stack is to *not* pop random elements. If you need to remove random items from a collection, use a collection that supports that such as `List<T>`.

Stack is a last-in, first-out (LIFO) collection, not a random access collection.

I'd suggest reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)

If you need to put something *on the stack* in random order, I'd suggest something like this:

```
List<Cards> wholeDeck = new List<Cards> { // initialize with a complete deck }
Random r = new Random();
Stack<Cards> stackOfCards = new Stack<Cards>();
while (wholeDeck.Count > 0) {
    var aCard = wholeDeck[r.Next(0,wholeDeck.Count)];     // grab a random card
    stackOfCards.Push(aCard);                              // push it on the stack
    wholeDeck.Remove(aCard);                              // remove it from the original list
}
```

A note on efficiency (since Servy bought it up): Servy is absolutely correct that this is not the most efficient way to shuffle. Why? Well because removal of an item from a list is O(*n*) and you'd have to do it *n* times so overall it's O(n2). while swapping items in a list (as in the Fisher-Yates algorithm) is O(1) which you'd do *n* times, so overall it's O(n). Of course, you'd still need to add the items from your shuffled list to the stack which is going to be O(n), so O(2n). With 52 items this probably makes very little difference (which is why I chose not to worry about it), but if you have a millions items, or you are shuffling a million decks of cards, then this might be something to worry about.

Now I assume that the OP's original question is for some kind of class and the objective is to learn something about collections, how they work and what they are good for and I think this does actually bring up an important comparison. Different collection types are good for different things. `List` gives you very fast, O(1) random access to any item in the list which makes it a great general purpose collection type. But this comes at a cost. The cost is that removal (and insertions, and sometimes additions) to the list are much slower. When you remove an item from a list the list has to be reorganized to move every item after the one you removed down one position so you can still index it quickly. When you insert (at some arbitary index) you have to move items up the list to make room. When you add to the end of the list, you *might* need to resize the backing store (in .NET it's an array) to make room (actually the same might be true of insertion) which requires copying the entire collection (the .NET list class gets around this by setting an initial capacity and when you hit that capacity it doubles the capacity rather than just adding one more element). So if you have a need for a collection where you are going to be inserting and removing items a lot, then List might not be the best choice.

So what about Stack? Stack gets around the insertion and removal problem by only letting you add (push) and remove (pop) from one spot in the collection. That way addition and removal is O(1) (for a fixed size stack at least). Which is great. But the cost is that you now lose the ability to access items in your collection in random order. Hence why the OP had difficulty figuring out how to shuffle *on the stack*. If you need the *nth* item on a stack you have to pop every item above it into a temporary stack, then look at the item you want, and then push all the items you remove back on.

Another collection type is the linked list. This collection has very fast removal (if you have a reference to the node) and insertion, and you can quickly find the next (and last in the case of a doubly linked list) node. But finding the *nth* node is O(n) because you have to walk the collection, counting nodes to find it.

Other collections have other properties and it's important to understand what you need from a collection before choosing the right one.

Comment: I have been told to use a stack to emulate a dealer dealing cards. but first I need to "shuffle" the cards. Can you not do this and I have misunderstood what has been asked of me?

Comment: @user3245390 Shuffle the cards *before* you put them into the stack, not after.

Comment: @user3245390: you can create a stack from anything that is IEnumerable. So first create a List<Card> initialized with your random deck of cards, then transform it to a stack like this : var myStackOfCards = new Stack<Card>(myListOfCards);

Comment: I'll accept this answer when it allows me to. I seem to have misunderstood what I was told to do, I was told to generate the cards randomly but he said it's fine if I work around it in my own way. Thanks for the answers everyone though.

Comment: @Servy: Of shuffle them *as you add them* to the stack.

Comment: @MattBurland Your shuffling algorithm is rather inefficient.  Removing a lot of items from the middle of a list is not a terribly efficient operation.  There are tons of very efficient shuffling algorithms that are quite easily discoverable.  As for shuffling while you add, sure, that's fine.  You nether gain nor lose anything doing that if you're using an effective shuffling algorithm.  Since we know that, in this case, he won't use the items in the stack until he's done adding them, the order they are added/shuffled isn't particularly important.

Comment: @MattBurland Care to elaborate on this please? PS Everyone I have updated the OP if anyone wants to help me out and tell me if my code will work :)

Comment: @Servy: Probably not the most efficient way, but since the question only has 52 items, it probably makes very little difference in practice. Plus it's very easy to understand what is happening which can be more difficult with some other algorithms and it very nicely matches what you would physically do to fill a card shoe.

Comment: @user3245390: My example code snippet is the elaboration. By randomly drawing a card from a list and pushing it onto the stack you are effectively shuffling it. As Servy points out it is *not* the best or most efficient shuffling algorithm, try [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for a more efficient solution.